# Length of array with indexes that are not consecutive integers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just realizing that JavaScript's native `.length` property works by adding one to the last numerical index of an array...  Anyone have a good solution for getting the real element length of an array with Indexes that are not consecutive?

```js
//Consecutively Indexed Array .length works good!
var test_array = [4,5,6,7,8];
$('#indexed-array').html("Consecutively Indexed Array Length: " + test_array.length);

//Unconsecutively Indexed Array .length No BUENO!
var test_array = [];
test_array[1] = 1;
test_array[3] = 2;
test_array[7] = 3;
$('#unconsecutive-indexed-array').html("Unconsecutively Indexed Array Length: " + test_array.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="indexed-array">
</p>

<p id="unconsecutive-indexed-array">
</p>
```

Comment: `arr.filter(Object).length` works since Object returns true-ish and filter() skips holes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys` and then get length

```
var array = [];
array[1] = 1;
array[3] = 3;
console.log(array.length); // 4
console.log(Object.keys(array).length); // 2
```

`Object.keys` is actually used to get an object's  properties/keys.

```
var obj = {a:'a', b:'b'};
Console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // ["a", "b"]
var arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(Object.keys(a)); //["0", "1", "2"]
```

Comment: this method uses a lot of extra resources compared to one that relies on an `in` operator; either a for-in loop, or the `if( i in arr)` of `[].filter()`

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as it iterates only those properties in array whose value is been `assigned`(*No matter what value is!*)

> `Callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array **which have assigned values**; it is not invoked for `indexes` which have been **deleted** or which have **never been assigned values**. Array elements which do not pass the callback test are **simply skipped**, and are **not included** in the new array.[[*Ref*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Description)]

```js
var test_array = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
$('#indexed-array').html("Consecutively Indexed Array Length: " + test_array.length);
var test_array = [];
test_array[1] = 0; //falsey values are not ignored
test_array[3] = 2;
test_array[7] = 3;
test_array[11] = undefined; //falsey values are not ignored
var filteredArray = test_array.filter(Object); //OR test_array.filter(function(){ return true; })
$('#unconsecutive-indexed-array').html("Unconsecutively Indexed Array Length: " + filteredArray.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="indexed-array"></p>
<p id="unconsecutive-indexed-array"></p>
```

Comment: plus 1, and I love this more `var filteredArray = test_array.filter( tem => item !== undefined )`

Comment: wouldn't this screw up for `[1,undefined,2]`? why hand-code a callback anyway?

Comment: @dandavis – Was that question for me ?

Comment: well, the above code seems to strip out elements set to `undefined` value, as opposed to just elements that are not own properties (like those implicitly defined by setting a higher length than the element count)... If you just want to remove holes, an `[].filter()` callback should return true each time.

Comment: `r=[1,undefined,2]; r.length=99;` - `r` with the tool should  count 3 explicit elements (not 2).

Comment: looking at how [].filter() works under the hood, it uses `if(key in arr)`, so anything that returns true works: `r=[1,undefined,2]; r.length=99; r.filter(Boolean.bind(1,1)).length == 3;` i like `Object` so i don't have to hand-code a callback or bind something, but again, anything that _always_ returns true works.

Comment: I am extremely confused.. `Boolean(Object(0))` => `true` but `Boolean(Object(undefined))` => `true`.. How `Object` is excluding those values then ?

Comment: `Object` always returns an object no matter what you feed it, and objects are always true. the droids you are actually looking for are buried in the native implementation of [].filter, look at a polyfill source code (and _.filter is NOT a polyfill)

Comment: I was missing the very first step.. I was assuming setting `r.length=99` will invoke `Object` passed as `callback` `99` times and I was amazed by how it could exclude those `undefined` values..

Comment: @dandavis — I hope my edit makes sense... Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and count.

```js
var test_array = [, 1, , 2, , , , 7],
    count = test_array.reduce(r => r + 1, 0);

console.log(count);
```